# Agglomerative ward linkage criteria

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

I am asking about ward linkage criteria how can i computing it ? i understand that single linkage merge the two clusters that have minimum distance and complete linkage merge the clusters have maximum distance in a proximity matrix, what about ward linkage how it work?

Comment: Actually complete linkage merge the clusters have **minimal** maximal distance between each pair of x in two compared clusters. Or else we would merge the clusters that are the most far away from us.

Comment: @Yonlif. what about ward how does it work ?!